# When attempting to apply range properties to a range or cells i get an error

Tags: excel, vba

In the following VBA code I am having a problem referencing ranges.

```
Dim counter_x As Long
Dim counter_y As Long
Dim OriginalEntries As Range

    ActiveSheet.Unprotect ("")
    Set OriginalEntries = Range("AZ1") 'Dummy range so its not empty for first union as that seems to cause issues
    With ActiveSheet
        For counter_y = 3 To 27 Step 3
            For counter_x = 1 To 41 Step 5
                If .Cells(counter_y, counter_x) <> "" Then
                    Set OriginalEntries = Union(OriginalEntries, .Cells(counter_y, counter_x))
                    'CRASHES HERE WHEN ORIGINALFILES EMPTY
                End If
            Next counter_x
        Next counter_y
    End With

    With OriginalEntries
        .Locked = True 'CRASHES HERE
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = -4.99893185216834E-02
        .Color = -52429
    End With

    ActiveSheet.Protect ("")
```

My original problem was I could not UNION OriginalEntries.  I temporarily solved this by initializing OriginalEntries with a dummy range.

Once I have all the ranges unioned, I try applying some range properties with no success.  I

What I have tried:

Changing

```
.cells(counter_x, counter_y)
```

to

```
.range(cells(counter_x, counter_y))
.range(.cells(counter_x, counter_y))
```

Both of those cause things to blow up on the UNION line

Also tried

```
.cells(counter_x, counter_y).locked = TRUE
```

and that blew up.

After the `With OriginalEntries` I used the following lines and it seems to work:

```
OriginalEntries.select
Selection.Lock
```

But I keep reading avoid using `select`, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's wrong with `OriginalEntries.Lock`?

Comment: “Blew up” is not a useful description of your problem.  What specific error are you getting and on which line?

Comment: `'.locked` crashes with run-time error '1004':

Comment: Pretty sure `Select OriginalEntries` is illegal, too

Comment: select OriginalEntries actually selected the correct cells.  Saw the change on the sheet while stepping through

Comment: Ok, but if that indeed works then there's quite a horrendous amount of implicit code going on for that to happen. If you want to select a `Range`, just invoke its `Select` method. i.e. you have a range object variable named `OriginalEntries`, so you do `OriginalEntries.Select` ...but you don't need to select anything to lock cells, see answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a dummy range, just to make sure you don't `Union` on `Nothing`. A simple function can ensure that:

```
Private Function Combine(ByVal range1 As Range, ByVal range2 As Range) As Range
    If Not range1 Is Nothing And Not range2 Is Nothing Then
        Set Combine = Union(range1, range2)
    Else If range1 Is Nothing Then
        Set Combine = range2
    Else If range2 Is Nothing Then
        Set Combine = range1
    End If
End Function
```

And now you can change this:

> ```
> Set OriginalEntries = Union(OriginalEntries, .Cells(counter_y, counter_x))
> ```

To that:

```
Set OriginalEntries = Combine(OriginalEntries, .Cells(counter_y, counter_x))
```

As for the `.Select` part...

> ```
> OriginalEntries.Select
> Selection.Lock
> ```

You don't need to `Select` the range, because at the end of the day what you want to invoke is `Range.Lock`... which should be `.Locked`, and it's a read/write property, so you want to assign it, like, this:

```
OriginalEntries.Locked = True
```

Comment: sorry I typed that in backwards, What I did was `OriginalEntires.select` followed by `selection.lock`

Comment: Forget `Selection` exists.

Comment: Trust me I dont want to use selection.  I was just using it as a test.

Comment: `OriginalEntries.locked = True` is throwing 1004 error.  I put it on the line right before with. and stepped to it

Comment: @ForwardEd when you type the `.` dot operator against an object variable, you get a list of all its members. `Selection` is `Object`, which is kind of a wrapper that stands for "just anything that's an object reference". When you type the `.` dot operator against an `Object` (or `Variant`), you get no intellisense/autocompletion dropdown, and the member call can only be resolved at run-time - so it effectively defers errors from compile-time (early bound) to run-time (late bound), and that is why it must be avoided: because implicit late-bound code is bug-prone =)

Comment: @ForwardEd make sure the sheet isn't protected. You can't set that property if the sheet is already protected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206106/discussion-between-forward-ed-and-mathieu-guindon).

Comment: Would it make a difference if the cell(s) were merged?

Comment: Ah, yes. Merged cells break things. You need to get the ranges' `MergeArea` and work with that.

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to Mathieu Guindon for taking a good chunk of time with me and going over various things.  Turns out the culprit is merged cells.

I was tinkering with a sudoku puzzle and was looking for a way to easily un/lock in the original puzzle, reset back to original, wipe puzzle clean as a way to practice my VBA programming skills.

The code was supposed to take this:

[image: Unlocked Puzz]

And turn it into this:

[image: Locked Puzz]

Since A3 is actually part of merged A3:E3, the code was screwing things up when I tried to apply cell property changes to only part of the merged cell.  It kept producing error 1004.

I over came the error, after looking into [MergeArea](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.mergearea) and not understanding it enough to work with, by ensuring the A3:E3 range was part of the selection an not just A3.  The revamped code looks as follows:

```
Sub Lock_Puzz()

Dim counter_x As Long
Dim counter_y As Long
Dim OriginalEntries As Range

    Sheet1.Unprotect ("")

    With Sheet1
        For counter_y = 3 To 27 Step 3
            For counter_x = 1 To 41 Step 5
                If Sheet1.Cells(counter_y, counter_x) <> "" Then
                    Set OriginalEntries = Combine(OriginalEntries, .Range(.Cells(counter_y, counter_x), .Cells(counter_y, counter_x + 4)))
                End If
            Next counter_x
        Next counter_y
    End With

    With OriginalEntries
        .Locked = True
        .Font.Color = -52429
        .Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .Interior.TintAndShade = -4.99893185216834E-02
    End With

    Sheet1.Protect ("")

End Sub
```

The `Combine` function is that provided by Mathieu Guindon which allows performing UNION when one of the ranges is empty.