# How to use MergeArea

Tags: excel, vba

It was suggested in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59778505/when-attempting-to-apply-range-properties-to-a-range-or-cells-i-get-an-error/59781008#59781008) to use [MergeArea](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.mergearea).  I looked it up but did not understand what I was reading enough to use it and found an alternate solution to my problem instead.

I was tinkering with a sudoku puzzle and was looking for a way to easily un/lock in the original puzzle, reset back to original, wipe puzzle clean as a way to practice my VBA programming skills.

The code was supposed to take this:

[image: Unlocked Puzz]

And turn it into this:

[image: Locked Puzz]

Since A3 is actually part of merged A3:E3, the code was screwing things up when I tried to apply cell property changes to only part of the merged cell.  It kept producing error 1004.  I got the code below working by ensuring the entire merged range was taken.

```
Sub Lock_Puzz()

Dim counter_x As Long
Dim counter_y As Long
Dim OriginalEntries As Range

    Sheet1.Unprotect ("")

    With Sheet1
        For counter_y = 3 To 27 Step 3
            For counter_x = 1 To 41 Step 5
                If Sheet1.Cells(counter_y, counter_x) <> "" Then
                    Set OriginalEntries = Combine(OriginalEntries, .Range(.Cells(counter_y, counter_x), .Cells(counter_y, counter_x + 4)))
                End If
            Next counter_x
        Next counter_y
    End With

    With OriginalEntries
        .Locked = True
        .Font.Color = -52429
        .Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .Interior.TintAndShade = -4.99893185216834E-02
    End With

    Sheet1.Protect ("")

End Sub
```

The `Combine` function is that provided by Mathieu Guindon in the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59778505/when-attempting-to-apply-range-properties-to-a-range-or-cells-i-get-an-error/59781008#59781008) which allows performing `UNION` when one of the ranges is empty.

My Unlock routine is similar but grabs the range A3:AS3  and changes Locked = False

```
Dim counter_x As Long
Dim Entries As Range

    With Sheet1
        For counter_x = 3 To 27 Step 3
            Set Entries = Combine(Entries, .Range("A" & counter_x & ":AS" & counter_x))
        Next counter_x
    End With

    Sheet1.Unprotect ("")
    With Entries
        .Locked = False
        .Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
        .Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        If Clear_Contents Then
            .ClearContents
        End If
    End With
    Sheet1.Protect ("")
```

Since this is just me tinkering around and trying to teach myself how to use VBA, can someone modify one of the codes to show how they would use [MergeArea](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.mergearea). (Or write your own!)